# How can i get an index for true positive, false positive, true negative, and false negative using scikit learn?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, metrics, confusion-matrix

we can calculate the counts of tp, fp, tn, and fn using [scikit-learn easily](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html).  However, I want to know the data index for each of tp, fp, tn, and fn.

for examples)

```
pred: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
true: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

tp = [0, 2]
fp = [1]
tn = [3, 5]
fn = [4]
```

How can I get it?
thanks for all reply.

Comment: didi you solve the issue? Does my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.array` and join `true` and `pred` into one list. To create unique combination use binary numeral system:

```
tn: 00 = 0
fp: 01 = 1
fn: 10 = 2
tp: 11 = 3
```

Now you can use `numpy.where` function to get list of indexes.

```py
import numpy as np

pred = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
true = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

unq = np.array([x + 2*y for x, y in zip(pred, true)])

tp = np.array(np.where(unq == 3)).tolist()[0]
fp = np.array(np.where(unq == 1)).tolist()[0]
tn = np.array(np.where(unq == 0)).tolist()[0]
fn = np.array(np.where(unq == 2)).tolist()[0]
```